# Can’t start mysql - error.log constantly written

Tags: mysql, innodb

Recently my sites hosted on an Ubuntu server started to display "Error establishing a database connection".

Connecting to the server, it looks like mysql is being restarted constantly (3s ago, 20s ago, etc, each time I try this command):

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service

 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Fri 2023-09-15 14:31:16 UTC; 3s ago
    Process: 8351 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8362 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 4541)
     Memory: 318.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─8362 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

My /var/log/mysql/error.log file is also growing rapidly. It contains lots of weird characters followed by text such as:

```
InnoDB: End of page dump
InnoDB: Page may be a transaction system page
2023-09-15T14:33:15.169775Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011899] [InnoDB] [FATAL] Unable to read page [page id: space=0, page number=5] into the buffer pool after 100 attempts. The most probable cause of this error may be that the table has been corrupted. Or, the table was compressed with with an algorithm that is not supported by this instance. If it is not a decompress failure, you can try to fix this problem by using innodb_force_recovery. Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ for more details. Aborting...
2023-09-15T14:33:15.169807Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: buf0buf.cc:4054:ib::fatal triggered thread 140275780638464
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2023-09-15T14:33:15Z UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
BuildID[sha1]=b0a6398207071378976beb42c50ef89be92e92db
Thread pointer: 0x5580f6f1c3f0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f9480134be0 thread_stack 0x100000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x41) [0x5580f29d9e71]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(print_fatal_signal(int)+0x39b) [0x5580f184efab]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_server_abort()+0x76) [0x5580f184f0f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_abort()+0xe) [0x5580f29d3e0e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0x349) [0x5580f2c77929]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(ib::fatal::~fatal()+0xd5) [0x5580f2c7a165]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch<Buf_fetch_normal>::read_page()+0x1aa) [0x5580f2ce2fba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch_normal::get(buf_block_t*&)+0x170) [0x5580f2ceec20]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Buf_fetch<Buf_fetch_normal>::single_page()+0x59) [0x5580f2ceed09]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(buf_page_get_gen(page_id_t const&, page_size_t const&, unsigned long, buf_block_t*, Page_fetch, ut::Location, mtr_t*, bool)+0x1fa) [0x5580f2cf02ea]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Double_write::get(mtr_t*)+0x56) [0x5580f2cf3c56]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(Double_write::init_v1(unsigned int&, unsigned int&)+0x11b) [0x5580f2cf8c1b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dblwr::v1::init()+0x1b) [0x5580f2cf8e2b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_start(bool)+0x1471) [0x5580f2c166a1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x2349496) [0x5580f2a1d496]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::bootstrap::DDSE_dict_init(THD*, dict_init_mode_t, unsigned int)+0x9e) [0x5580f27564ae]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(dd::upgrade_57::do_pre_checks_and_initialize_dd(THD*)+0x1a9) [0x5580f29abf89]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1240896) [0x5580f1914896]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x289d0fd) [0x5580f2f710fd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8609) [0x7f94a20cb609]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f94a1c9c133]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 1
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I think the problem was originally caused by a full hard drive. I tried to restore an old backup of the server but the oldest I have seems to already have the problem.

I’m completely stuck and out of solutions. What can I try now?

Comment: Let's see my.cnf.  How much RAM do you have?  Is the disk full, or nearly full, now?

Answer (score 0):

In your my.cnf [mysqld] section you need a line for

```
thread_cache_size=64
```

if the line does not exist in the section, add to the [mysqld] section, please.

We are here to assist.